# must specify a collection in MongoDB when exporting a database with mongoexport

Tags: mongodb

Using MongoDB 4.2 with the latest mongocompass version, I am running

```
mongoexport --uri="mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/mydbname"
```

(Filling out the username and password appropriately of course)

But I get an error saying `must specify a collection` even though I want to export the whole database.

Also I am pretty sure I am using the right password, but where I can I check to make sure it's the right one?

And I do want to use mongoexport instead of mongodump because when I run mongodump I get

```
Failed: can't create session: could not connect to server: connection() : auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

From the mongoexport [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoexport/)

> You must specify the collection to export.

That is a design limitation and requirement of that specific tool.

Answer (score 0):

because you specified a db (mydbname) but not a collection. A database can have several collections (like tables in traditional database systems), and each collection can have multiple Documents (like tables in traditional database systems).

To specify the collection you can write:
mongoexport --uri="mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/mydbname" --collection="myCOllection"